# Issue overriding application properties in Spring-boot (profile-specific) application launched with PropertiesLauncher

Tags: java, properties, spring-boot, overriding

I'm having difficulty trying to override a property declared in a profile-specific application properties file on the classpath with another value declared in an overrides file on the file system.

I have an auto-configured Spring-boot application (that is, using `@EnableAutoconfiguration`) that has multiple profiles, which I launch using `PropertiesLauncher` rather than `JarLauncher` (the reason having to do with deployment constraints - I need to deploy an exploded directory rather than an archive into a **read-only** filesystem.)

Within the root of my application, I have some profile-specific application properties, for example:

```
application-dev.properties
application-qa.properties
application-prd.properties
```

And let's say, for the sake of argument that `application-dev.properties` contains:

```
foo.bar=baz
foo.baz=other
```

For any environment, it may be necessary to override an *existing* property, as well as supply an *absent* one (like a production password, for example), and the issue I'm seeing is with overriding properties already declared in an `application-${profile}.properties` file on the classpath. (Supplying properties not present in the classpath file works fine, this is **not** the issue.)

Say I have an overrides properties file in a file system location such as:

```
/local/appname/dev/overrides/application.properties
```

and I want to override the property, `foo.bar`, as well as declare a new property, `foo.password`.

Therefore the contents of the overrides file are:

```
foo.bar=overridden-value
foo.password=something
```

When I launch the application, I use a command line something like this:

```
java -Dspring.config.location=file:/local/appname/dev/overrides/ 
     -Dspring.profiles.active=dev 
     org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher 
     --debug &
```

The issue I am seeing is that although `foo.password`, the property ***not*** declared in the `application-dev.properties` file ***is*** picked up, the override of `foo.bar` is ignored - I still see the value, `baz` from `application-dev.properties` rather than the value, `overridden-value` from `/local/appname/dev/overrides/application.properties`.

With the `--debug` option enabled, I can see the `ConfigFileApplicationListener` logging that it has loaded both the overrides file (from the filesystem) and the profile-specific file (from the classpath), ***in that order***.

I'm tempted into the perhaps naïve conclusion that because the overrides file is listed first, it is being loaded first then overridden by the 'default' profile-specific file from the classpath, which is listed later. I do appreciate however, that order of listing in the log doesn't necessarily correlate with behaviour. And I have tried varying the order of paths declared on the `spring.config.location` property, so that `classpath:` is listed before `file:...` but this hasn't helped and I't not convinced it would anyway, given that the Spring-boot documentation clearly states that the default properties locations are always searched even if you supply a value for `spring.config.location`.

The Spring-boot documentation is very specific about the order that properties are resolved for a Spring-boot executable JAR, in *descending* order of precedence:

1. Command line arguments.
2. Java System properties (`System.getProperties()`).
3. OS environment variables.
4. JNDI attributes from `java:comp/env`
5. A `RandomValuePropertySource` that only has properties in `random.*`.
6. Application properties ***outside*** of your packaged jar (`application.properties` including YAML and profile variants).
7. Application properties packaged ***inside*** your jar (`application.properties` including YAML and profile variants).
8. `@PropertySource` annotations on your `@Configuration` classes.
9. Default properties (specified using `SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties`).

Take note of lines 6 and 7 - properties ***outside*** over properties ***inside*** your jar.

What's not stated, as far as I can see, and which may be the source of my confusion/issue, is what happens when you're ***not*** using a JAR but an exploded directory (and therefore `PropertiesLauncher`.)

If the behaviour of an exploded directory were consistent with what's stated for a JAR, I'd expect that the values of properties declared in `/local/appname/dev/overrides/application.properties` would override any of the same name declared in `classpath:application-dev.properties`, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Also noted from the Spring-boot documentation (appendix C.4 on `PropertiesLauncher`) is mention of the `loader.home` property, which is described as '... [the] Location of additional properties file, *e.g.* `/opt/app` (defaults to `${user.dir}`)'.

So I tried using `loader.home` instead of `spring.config.location`, but to no avail.

(Update: I also tried using `loader.config.location` and I have two notes: it seems to want a file rather than a directory (so its behaviour is ***not*** analogous with `spring.config.location`), and when I *did* supply a file path rather than the parent directory, it still didn't help.)

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong, or what incorrect assumption(s) I'm making?

Comment: I think maybe profile-specific properties always take precedence. Did you try a local `application-dev.properties`?

Comment: @Dave - I have tried everything that has been discussed here.Can u plz help? My question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635163/spring-boot-externalizing-properties-not-working/36635367?noredirect=1#comment60919038_36635367

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks, Dave, your suggestion was 100% correct.

If I rename the properties file in `/local/appname/dev/overrides` to `application-dev.properties` then the property values from that file ***do*** override the ones in `classpath:application-dev.properties`.

I was sure I *had* tried this combination yesterday, but I think what must have stopped it working was when I was playing around with specifying the `spring.config.location` and got that wrong so it wasn't looking for the override file in the right place.

Comment: @Dave - I have tried everything that has been discussed here.Can u plz help? My question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635163/spring-boot-externalizing-properties-not-working/36635367?noredirect=1#comment60919038_36635367